# How can I freeze on one pane of a JTabbedPane?

Tags: java, swing

Under certain circumstances, I need a JTabbedPane to remain on one pane until the user supplies certain information.  Essentially, when this circumstance occurs, I need the current pane to become modal.

How can I implement this?  I was thinking I could catch whatever event is triggered when the pane changes, and reset back to the pane I want to stick on.  But I'm worried that this won't be quite right, that depending on when the event actually fires the transition to the new pane will happen *after* I call the method to set the pane to the pane I want, or some other similar race condition.  Is there a better way?  Is there a way I can make this approach work?

Comment: You can't use a JDialog or JOptionPane?

Comment: @ChadNC, I thought about that, and actually I would prefer that option, but in this case, the user needs to take steps on this pane to change the circumstances to eliminate the condition that I need to freeze for.  And there are multiple ways they can alleviate that condition, using the controls on that pane.  If I pop up a modal dialog, they lose access to all those controls.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would suggest setting the other tabs to disabled. This has a positive effect of providing the user feedback that they cannot click out of the tab. Otherwise they may be madly clicking and wondering why it will not let them leave the tab.

Simply set them enabled again after the required fields are completed.

Comment: Also make it very clear to the user what they need to fix. I can't think of many things more frustrating that being stuck on a modal anything that's waiting for some input I don't know how to enter.

Comment: @TwentyMiles Yup, I usually highlight the field red or yellow.. make it stand out.

Comment: This is my accepted answer, but I used pieces of all the others; in particular, it was ChadNC who clued me into the setEnabledAt() method (which I couldn't seem to find on my own, despite being fairly proficient at reading JavaDocs), and Carlos' solution almost worked for me and made a good stopgap solution to get the basic concept working.

Answer (score 2):

just disable the JTabbedPane:

```
pane.setEnabled(false);
```

and enable it if all fields are correctly set (or whatever condition)

Comment: Pretty cool!  Slightly off because it greys out the current tab, but the current pane does stay active, so it works.  I think I'll go for trying to disable each individual tab, though, if I can work it out correctly.

Comment: @skiphoppy - if you don't want to grey out the current tab, you can go by @Chris solutions: use `JTabbedPane.setEnablebAt(int, boolean)` to disable each tab but the current.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a [CardLayout](http://java.sun.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/CardLayout.html) along with JPanels to do what you want and not use JTabbedPanes. Since you need to use the tabbed panes, I would suggest that once the condition has been reached that you want to force the user to stay on that tab set that tab to be the selected one by using.

```
setTabComponentAt(int index, Component component)
```

or

```
setSelectedIndex(int index)
```

Set a flag indicating that the user should not be able to proceed until completing whatever it is you want them to do and have all the other tabs be disabled using `setEnabledAt(int index, boolean enabled)`
.
Once the user has completed what they needed in order to continue set the flag accordingly and reenable the other tabs.

I haven't the time to try that solution out but I think it should work.